# Query authors/users that have published products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to know if it is possible to pass some args to WP_User_Query that would allow me to select Authors that have some published WooCommerce products. Something like has_published_posts but for products. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: WP_User_Query allows you to access only `users` and `usermeta` table only so only way to get author for published product can be done using `WP_Query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option "has_published_posts"

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( 
    array( 
        'has_published_posts' => array( 'product' ) 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I was looking for :)